# Diffrent types for one variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set gunS to Shotgun type or AR15 type but dont know how and this code dont work

```
public Shotgun gunS2;
public AR15 gunS3;

public MonoBehaviour gunS;

private void Start()
{
    set();
}

public void set()
{    

    if(gunT.name == "Shotgun")
    {
        gunS = gunT.GetComponent<Shotgun>();
    }
    else
    {
        gunS = gunT.GetComponent<AR15>();            
    }
}
```

Comment: You need either introduce some base type/interface which both `Shotgun` and `AR15` will inherit/implement (like you do with `MonoBehaviour` for it, but something more specific) or use something like [`OneOf`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) which, I would say, usually is less preferable option in such cases.

Comment: Use a common base class or interface ...

Comment: Your variable gunT is undeclared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them a common interface.

```
interface IWeapon
{
}

class AR15 : IWeapon
{
}

class Shotgun : IWeapon
{
}
```

If your classes are defined this way (you obviously have to add implementation) then you can write a variable that can contain any `IWeapon`.

```
public IWeapon gunS;

public void set()
{     
    if(gunT.name == "Shotgun")
    {
        gunS = gunT.GetComponent<Shotgun>();
    }
    else
    {
        gunS = gunT.GetComponent<AR15>();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable gunT is undeclared, like in the post sample code, what is gunT? I understand is not the same than gunS

Comment: I imagine it is a member field or property that returns an object that has a `GetComponent<T>()` method. I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a base class and/or interface

```
public interface IWeapon 
{
    // whatever public properties and methods shall be accessible through this interface
}

public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour //, IWeapon
{
    // whatever fields, properties and methods are shared between all subtypes

    // if using the interface implementation of it
}
```

and then

```
public class ShotGun : Weapon
// or if for some reason you don't want a common base class
//public class ShotGun : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon
{
    // whatever additional or override fields, properties and methods this needs

    // or if using the interface the implementation of it
}
```

and

```
public class AK74 : Weapon
// or if for some reason you don't want a common base class
//public class AK74 : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon
{
    // whatever additional or override fields, properties and methods this needs

    // or if using the interface the implementation of it
}
```

Then simply drag the according object/component into the exposed slot in the Inspector in Unity.

There is no need for your `gunT` field (wherever it comes from)

```
// Already reference this via the Inspector in Unity
// then you don't need your Start/set method AT ALL!
public Weapon gunS;
```

If for some reason this is not an option e.g. if using only the interface

```
public IWeapon gunS;
```

there still is no need to check the name or specify the type further. [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) will return the first encountered component of the given type or a type inheriting from it. You can simply do

```
void Awake()
{
    // as fallback if for whatever reason you can't directly reference it via the Inspector
    // (which doesn't seem to be the case since somewhere you get gunT from ...)
    if(!gunS) gunS = /*Wherever this comes from*/ gunT.GetComponent<Weapon>();
    // or i only using the interface
    //if(!gunS) gunS = /*Wherever this comes from*/ gunT.GetComponent<IWeapon>();
}
```